# IE 9 Ajax Request posts null values to MVC App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have an application posting to an asp.net MVC webservice via Ajax.

This seems to work like a champ in all browsers **except** IE 9. What could be causing this?

**The javascript**

```
console.log(data);
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '//localhost:65201/User/CreateAsynch',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
         // Do stuff
    },
    error: function (xhr, msg) {
        // Do stuff
}});
```

**The Controller**

This is what happens when I post in IE vs other browsers (Chrome, in this example)

See how some of the values are populating?

[image: Chrome Result]

Then there's IE9

[image: IE9]

### Here's what the requests look like (from fiddler)

**Chrome**

```
POST http://localhost:65201/User/CreateAsynch HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:65201
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 184
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:56076
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:56076/retail/registrationform/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Username=drew.j.wyatt%40gmail.com&FirstName=Drew&LastName=Wyatt&Email=drew.j.wyatt%40gmail.com&RawPassword=boom&RawConfirmPassword=boom&CountryCode=USA&UserTypeID=2&RegisterForStore=31
```

**IE9**

```
POST http://localhost:65201/User/CreateAsynch HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:56076
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:65201
Content-Length: 184
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Username=drew.j.wyatt%40gmail.com&FirstName=Drew&LastName=Wyatt&Email=drew.j.wyatt%40gmail.com&RawPassword=boom&RawConfirmPassword=boom&CountryCode=USA&UserTypeID=2&RegisterForStore=31
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what's the version of your jquery?